# Typescript Inversify: How to bind interface with type parameters

Tags: typescript, inversifyjs

I want to bind an interface that has a type parameter but I am don't how it's done.

**Interface**

```
...
export interface ITestHelper<Entity extends ObjectLiteral> {
  doSomething(builder: SelectQueryBuilder<Entity>,
    pagination: IPaginationParams): SelectQueryBuilder<Entity>;
}
export const TTestHelper = Symbol.for('ITestHelper');
```

**ContainerModule**
I have tried binding like below but there's an error - Generic type 'ITestHelper' requires 1 type argument(s)

```
...
export const TestContainerModule = new ContainerModule((bind: interfaces.Bind) => {
    bind<ITestHelper>(TTestHelper)
    .to(TestHelper)
    .inSingletonScope();
});
```

Comment: Please share reproducable example

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it I updated the binding to be

```
...
export const TestContainerModule = new ContainerModule((bind: interfaces.Bind) => {
    bind<ITestHelper<ObjectLiteral>>(TTestHelper)
    .to(TestHelper)
    .inSingletonScope();
});
```